# How to highlight dates in excel using condional formatting dependent on Consumer Name

Tags: excel

I have a table with Consumer Names in it and specific dates they are busy.

I can format cells based on a range in-between the certain dates. But I want this to be done so that it highlights the dates depending on the Consumer Name as well.

Answer (score 0):

If column `A` contains the names and column `B` contains a specific date, starting at row `2`.

```
    A      B
1 Name    Date      
2 name A  2016-04-13
3 name B  2016-04-13        
4 name C  2016-04-13
```

In your conditional format dialog enter the formula

```
=IF($A2="name A";TRUE;FALSE)
```

for `B2:B4`. As you can see `B2` will change depending on your format.